# Необходима разъяснить с запросом UPDATE. Как можно обновить,таблицу если заранее не знаешь количество переменных

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

Суть в том что в моей работе по требованиям преподавателя у таблицы есть такая функция , добавлять и удалять столбцы и поэтому я заранее не знаю сколько столбцов

мне нужно обновить . И вот столкнулся с проблемой . Растолкуйте пожалуйста друзья.

$value - это массив , который принимает значения , которые мы вставляем в таблицу. преобразуем его в int и все работает

существует массив $columnnames в котором находятся все столбцы таблицы

переменная $column берет значение из массива $columnnames

в запросе вместо переменной $column должно быть название столбца

возможно какая-то проблема с типами , но переменная $column имеет тип string

если $column = 'id' то все работает

код ниже не работает , при нажатии на кнопку и "выполнении скрипта" просто открывается новая страница.

Я не знаю и не понимаю как это сделать.

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "root", "college");
 
      $table = 'astronom';
      $table = $mysqli->real_escape_string($table);
      $column =$columnnames[1]; 
      
 
      $value = (int)$value[1];
      
      $sql = mysqli_query($mysqli, "UPDATE `{$table}` 
      SET `{$column}` = $value
      WHERE `Студенческий`={$_GET['red_id']}   ");
       if ($sql) {
        echo '<p>Успешно!</p>';
      } else {
        echo '<p>Произошла ошибка: ' . mysqli_error($mysqli) . '</p>';
      }
```

Comment: Да ты хотя бы разберись, где у тебя проблема, в MySQL или в PHP...

Comment: Кажется, проблема в запросе, вряд ли же у вас поле в таблице называется "Студенческий". Не хватает данных о структуре таблицы/таблиц, чтобы сложить полностью картинку

Comment: @lezhni в таблице есть столбец "Студенческий" и имеет тип int а также поле которое необходимо изменить имеет тип int